# Banner Location or Banner Position

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I'm preparing a text for the advertise section of the website. The users will be able to post ads and/or rent some banner space.
There are several different "spaces" on different pages of the website to rent. Which is the correct phrase:

> 1) Various ***locations*** and sizes are available for your banner.

or

> 2) Various ***positions*** and sizes are available for your banner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using http://www.quirks.com/advertise/online/web_ads.aspx as an example, you'll see that both location and position are used in describing how ads will be placed. As a designer, my instinct is to go with position since the context involves site layout.

Comment: I agree with @lonehorseend, *location* could be taken to mean either the site url/domain or the page layout (which I think what you want to say), while *position* is clearly related to the page layout.

Answer (score 1):

"Position" as you are using it here is pretty much a synonym for "location". Either one works.

I tend to think of "position" as meaning a place relative to other things, while "location" is more absolute. Like I might say, "We positioned the new store ten miles north of the old store", meaning we put it there because the relationship to the placement of the old store is in some way important. But if we just thought the new place was a good one for reasons having nothing to do with where the old one was, I think I'd say "We located the new store in Albany".

But this is a fine shade of meaning.